# How do I create relationships between a single table?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

[image]

I have the above tables in a database I'm designing right now, in MySQL. The primary purpose of the database is to create Bill Of Materials for a database and enforce revision control on these Bill Of Materials.

The Parts table follows Single Table Inheritance and has 3 different types of parts: Connectors, Terminals, Seals.

Brief Description Each Type

**Connector**: These are automotive grade connectors used in the manufacturing of automotive wiring harnesses.

**Terminals**: A connector has crimped wires inserted into it. A Terminal is crimped onto a wire in order to create a solder-less joint. These terminals then mate with their counterparts when the connecter is mated with it's counterpart in a vehicle.

**Seals**: These are special type of seals that are inserted onto the the wire in order to prevent water/dust getting through to the interconnection.

A connector can be used with multiple types of terminal and a terminal can also be used with multiple types of connectors.

The relationship between a connector and a seal is similar. A seal and terminal have no relationship.

What I'm aiming for:

1. If the user is browsing some part, I would like the view to show all it's related/associated parts. For instance, if Connector id 1 can be used with 5 different types of terminals, I would like all these terminals be shown in the view.
2. Similarly, when Terminal is being viewed, I would like all the different connectors that it can be used with shown as well.
3. Furthermore, a Connector can have substitute parts and I would like to relate that as well. This is a one-to-many relationship as a connector can have multiple substitutes.
4. And finally, a Connector can have multiple counter-parts and I would like these to be related as well.

I'm new to database design and I'm having trouble seeing the forest through the trees. Personally, I think I should ditch the Single Table idea and go with separate tables for Connectors, Seals and Terminals and draw up relationships between them.

That still answer how I can show substitutes and counter-part connectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for an alternative to single table inheritance, look up class table inheritance.  In your case, this would mean four tables in place of parts:  Parts, Connectors, Seals, and Terminals.  If each of the last three tables use shared primary key off of the parts table,  you'll enforce the 1-to-1 nature of the "is-a" relationship, but not the mutually exclusive feature.

More to the point, you have not modelled the relationships between parts and other parts that you outlined in your verbal description.  Those relationships may be inherent in the BOMS you create, but they aren't obvious here.  If you model those relationships, will it make the database more functional?  I don't know, offhand.

If you are having trouble seeing the forest for the trees, it may be that you are trying to design the solution without having analyzed the problem.  I have found it handy to analyze the subject matter using the ER model.  This breaks the subject matter down into entities, relationships, and attributes, but doesn't say anything about table design.  Hint:  your model is a relational model, not an ER model, even though you use ER diagramming conventions.  Again, in my experience, once I have an ER model that describes the problem, it's easy (although tedious) to devise a relational model that designs the solution.